# Transformation introduced infinite values in continuous y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, boxplot, phyloseq

I want to set my y-axis to log-scale to make the visualization better readable.

Before doing so my data looks correctly displayed . [without log-scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbhtP.png)

```
plot_bar(ent40, "phylum", fill="kingdom", facet_grid=~sampleID)+
geom_col(aes(fill=kingdom), position="stack")+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = comma_format(big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ","))
```

When I change it to log-scale on y-axis I get the following error messages:

```
Warning messages:
1: Transformation introduced infinite values in continuous y-axis 
2: Transformation introduced infinite values in continuous y-axis 
3: Removed 119 rows containing missing values (geom_bar). 
4: Removed 119 rows containing missing values (geom_col).
```

On top my plot's scale gets completely out of proportion.

[after transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCTEP.png)

Comment: Round the values to a specific number of decimal places; that should solve the problem.

Comment: The strange thing is: my values are "whole numbers".

Comment: The data won't be whole numbers after calculating the logarithm.

Comment: Where do I add an argument to round the values than?

Comment: You don't have it in the code where you took the `log`, and I don't know how you're going to use the data next, but this you can round where you calculated the logarithm. This is an example: `round(log(runif(10, 100, 1000)), digits = 2)`. I'm just using `runif()` here to create random numbers. This rounds to two decimals places.

Comment: For the danger of asking a complete stupid question. I think I am really stuck: my goal is to just transform the y-axis in order to compare samples better that have a wide range of observations. So I don't want to tansform my actual values just the scales.

Comment: `plot_bar(ent40, "phylum", fill="kingdom", facet_grid=~sampleID)+
geom_col(aes(fill=kingdom), position="stack")+
  scale_y_log10(labels = comma_format(big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ","))` I just wanted a log_scale. Is this the wrong approach?

Comment: You can scale the data within the graph only without actually changing your data. From the images you provided, it seems like using the log scale may be a good idea. Is the data exponential? If you want a better answer, add some data to your post: use `dput()`.  Alternatively, I would encourage you to see what the data looks like when you take the log outside the graph.